# LWC SecureWindow's window.scrollX and window.scrollY returning 0 regardless of scroll amount?

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service

I'm noticing that `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` are returning `0` from the Locker Service's SecureWindow wrapper regardless of how far the window is scrolled in either direction.

Not only does it return `0` when called from a Lightning Web Component, but also when queried from the console in Developer Tools (see screenshot). I've tested in different browsers, seeing `0` there as well.

[image: View of the SecureWindow's scrollX and scrollY properties showing 0 for both.]

I don't believe this has always been the case because I use `window.scrollY` to help position some components relative to the window's scroll position and found this to work previously. Has anyone else come across this?

To clarify, I'm seeing this in an Experience site (previously Community) with custom Lightning Web Components.